# How to loop over multiple files, do some operations and write all variables from a loop in a file?

Tags: r

I am new to R so forgive is this is basic.

I am reading in some table:

```
library(data.table)
require(magrittr); require(tidyr)

x=fread("merged_plot_SG", header=TRUE)

> head(x)
          gene_id chr  min_POS  max_POS      rs_id pvalue_G pvalue_E     metaP
1 ENSG00000020922  11 94212567 95223359 rs11605546   0.1367   0.9353 0.2670442
2 ENSG00000020922  11 94212567 95223359   rs566917   0.2740   0.2275 0.9363864
3 ENSG00000020922  11 94212567 95223359 rs12286498   0.8961   0.3347 0.5552598
4 ENSG00000020922  11 94212567 95223359  rs7934178   0.9043   0.3353 0.5510581
5 ENSG00000020922  11 94212567 95223359 rs16924610   0.9047   0.3353 0.5507136
6 ENSG00000020922  11 94212567 95223359  rs2508783   0.8685   0.1382 0.3517432
...
```

in that table I want to extract all unique(x$chr), in this case:

```
    > unique(x$chr)
[1] 11  3  6  7 20 17  2 12  1 10  4 19  9 22
```

than for each of those unique numbers I want to load a file, like for example the first one here is 11, so I would do:

```
b=fread("/mydir/bed_chr_11.bed")
```

and next ones:

```
b=fread("/mydir/bed_chr_3.bed")
b=fread("/mydir/bed_chr_6.bed")
...
```

next I would do these two operations:

```
 x00=x %>%
  inner_join(b, by = c("rs_id" = "V4")) %>%
  select(gene_id, chr, rs_id, pvalue_G, pvalue_E, V2, V3)


x11=x00 %<>%
  unite(snp, chr, V3, remove = FALSE)
```

so on the end I would have all those data frames:

```
x11,x3,x6,x7,x20,x17,x2,x12,x1,x10,x4,x19,x9,x22
```

then I would join them all in a single data frame and write to a file:

```
x.n <- c('x11','x3','x6','x7','x20','x17','x2','x12','x1','x10','x4','x19','x9','x22')
x.list <- lapply(x.n, get)
xx=do.call(rbind, x.list)

colnames(xx)[6] <- "pvalue"
write.table(xx, "ready_plot_SG", quote=F, col.names=TRUE,row.names = F)
```

Can you please help how to do all of these in one script and using a loop?

Thanks!

EDIT: following advice bellow I came to this point:

```
require(dplyr)
library(data.table)
require(magrittr); require(tidyr)

x=fread("merged_plot_RGL", header=TRUE)
num=unique(x$chr)

files=list.files(path = "/anika/bed/", pattern = "\\.bed$", full.names = FALSE)

data_dir <- "/anika/bed"

#loop over the initial files
for(i in num){
  file <- paste0(data_dir,"/", "bed_chr_",num[i],".bed")  # loaded .bed file


    xx <- lapply(file, function(z){
    b <- fread(z, header = TRUE)
    data.table(
        x %>%
          inner_join(b, by = c("rs_id" = "V4")) %>%
          select(gene_id, chr, rs_id, pvalue_G, pvalue_E, V2, V3) %>%
          unite(snp, chr, V3, remove = FALSE)
       )

})
  #We can combine them using data.tables 'rbindlist'
  x_final <- rbindlist(xx)
  #now we can use data.tables 'fwrite' to output the table to a file
  names(x_final)[6] <- "pvalue"
  fwrite(x_final, "test_rgl.txt", quote = "F", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

But I got this error:

```
    Error: `by` can't contain join column `V4` which is missing from RHS
Execution halted
```

Comment: A simple idea: use `paste0` and `for`: as in, `for (i in seq_along(Uniques)){ y[[i]] <- fread(paste0("/mydir/bed_chr_", Uniques[[i]]))  #etc. code depending on i }`. However, I highly suggest recoding this with the `tidyverse` package. In particular using `readr` to read in data using, processing file paths, etc. with `fs`, and using `walk` and `map` functions to forgo using `for` loops.

Comment: thanks, I will try this idea with paste0, I am very new to all this.  Would my Uniques variable be=unique(x$chr)

Comment: Yes, `Uniques <- unique(x$chr)` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your question i will try to provide an answer to the best of my ability.
It seems we have multiple files in each step. 
I suggest using an outside for loop with an inside apply function, which you can use to read and perform the desired transformations.

```
initial_dir <- "directory to the folder with the initial data"
data_dir <- "directory to the folder containing the secondary data"

file_names <- c("lots of file names") #1: Insert any number of files here from which to read numbers for the bed_chr_[nr].bed files here
#loop over the initial files
for(i in file_names){
  file <- paste0(initial_dir,"/", i)
  x <- fread(file, header = TRUE)
  #combine secondary path and name 
  secondary_files <- paste0(data_dir,"/bed_chr_", unique(x[, [Insert the column for which the value for the bed_chr_[nr].bed files are in the intitial variable here <--]), ".bed")  #2: insert column name (note i added unique)
  #Apply the desired transformation
  xx <- lapply(secondary_files, function(z){ #lapply will apply the 'function' to each element in 'secondary_files'.
      b <- fread(z) 
      data.table( #apply the transformation and return a table to the list
        x %>% 
          inner_join(b, by = c("rs_id" = "V4")) %>%
          select(gene_id, chr, rs_id, pvalue_G, pvalue_E, V2, V3) %>%
          unite(snp, chr, V3, remove = FALSE)
       )
    }) #after the lapply has run xx contains all the tables from the bed_chr_[numbers].bed files. All will have been read.
  #xx is now a list that contains all the table after applying 
  #We can combine them using data.tables 'rbindlist'
  x_final <- rbindlist(xx)
  #now we can use data.tables 'fwrite' to output the table to a file
  names(x_final)[6] <- "pvalue"
  fwrite(x_final, "ready_plot_sg.txt", quote = "F", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE) #here all the bed_chr_[numbers].bed files will be output into a single combined file
}
```

Notes:
I have used paste0 instead of paste. They both combine strings in R, the difference is that `paste0` has standard argument `sep = ""` where `paste` inserts a white space by default 
`lapply` will apply a function over a list, vector or similar and output the result in a list. `vapply` or `sapply` could be used as well, but do not necessarily give you a list as a result, which in this case is desirable in order to use `rbindlist` without any additional parameters.
For the purpose of my example i have assumed there was no mistakes in your transformation of b.

:::Edit:::
From the new snippet added by the questioneer, i will in the special case rewrite the code i posted, to show how the two were meant to be merged:

```
require(dplyr);library(data.table);require(magrittr); require(tidyr)
initial_dir <- "" #The base directory in 'edit' was none ("merged_plot_RGL" is in working directory)
data_dir <- "anika/bed"

file_names <- c("merged_plot_RGL") #1: I inserted the merged_plot_RGL, as this contains the labels for the 'bed' files.
#Note: This loop is now redundant as we only have 1 file. But for illustration it was kept (i will only take on 'merged_plot_RGL' as a value)
for(i in file_names){
  file <- i #2: Sets current file to merged_plot_RGL. paste0 removed as intial_dir was empty ("")
  x <- fread(file, header = TRUE)  #3: loads in merged_plot_RGL as a data.table
  #4: combine secondary path and name (Note: I extract the number from x's chr column)
  secondary_files <- paste0(data_dir,"/bed_chr_", unique(x[, chr]), ".bed")  
  #5: Apply the desired transformation via lapply (Note: xx becomes a list of transformed data from the bed files)
  xx <- lapply(secondary_files, function(z){ 
      b <- fread(z) #5.1: First read in the .bed file (done 1 by 1)
      data.table( #5.2: apply the transformation and return a table to the list
        x %>% 
          inner_join(b, by = c("rs_id" = "V4")) %>% #Note: Questioneers error came
          select(gene_id, chr, rs_id, pvalue_G, pvalue_E, V2, V3) %>%
          unite(snp, chr, V3, remove = FALSE)
       )
    }) 
  #Note: After the lapply has run, and read in each .bed file, xx is now a list of .bed data tables that have been transformed by inner join, select and unite.
  #6: We can combine them using data.tables 'rbindlist'
  x_final <- rbindlist(xx)
  #7: now we can use data.tables 'fwrite' to output the table to a file
  names(x_final)[6] <- "pvalue"
  fwrite(x_final, "ready_plot_sg.txt", quote = "F", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE) 
}
```

::: Edit 2 ::: 
shorter version with easier error reading.

```
require(dplyr);library(data.table);require(magrittr); require(tidyr)
data_dir <- "anika/bed"

file_names <- c("merged_plot_RGL") 
x <- fread("merged_plot_RGL", header = TRUE)  
secondary_files <- paste0(data_dir,"/bed_chr_", unique(x[, chr]), ".bed")  
bed_files <- lapply(secondary_files, fread)
xx <- rbindlist(bed_files)
xx2 <- x %>%
  inner_join(xx, by = c("rs_id" = "V4")) 
xx3 <- xx2 %>% 
  select(gene_id, chr, rs_id, pvalue_G, pvalue_E, V2, V3) 
xx4 <- xx3 %>%
  unite(snp, chr, V3, remove = FALSE)
names(xx4)[6] <- "pvalue"
fwrite(xx4, "ready_plot_sg.txt", quote = "F", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this elaborate answer. Can you please just clarify what would be in file_names vector, is that vector of these .bed files:bed_chr_1.bed, bed_chr_2.bed...or? I have 22 of these .bed files. Also is initial_dir dir from where I load "merged_plot_SG" data frame? and is data_dir directory where my .bed files are located?

Comment: because I just have one file which I load initially: "merged_plot_SG", and multiple .bed files which I load as I am looping trough different unique, chr numbers: unique(x$chr)

Comment: Hello anikaM 

the 'file_names' would be the initial file that is loaded. So for your case it would be 'merged_plot_SG'. 
So in your case that would simply replace the 'lots of file names'. 

The initial_dir is combined with 'file names' so it would be the directory where you want to load the 'merged_plot_SG' file. 
'data_dir' is then the directory for all of your bed_chr_[].bed' files

Example:
paste0(intial_dir,"/",i) would become "C:/temp/merged_plot_SG" if the file was situated in C:/temp 
You can always type ?[function name] to get the help site for the function with explanation

Comment: yes I run it as you explained and this is what I got: Error in `[.data.table`(x, , file_column) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'file_column' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..file_column]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

Comment: when the file_column would be defined?

Comment: Hello anikaM, file column would simply be replaced by the name of the column which contains the file name. :-) 
So if the column was named 'bed_number' i would insert 'bed_number' insead of 'file_column'.

Comment: yes but the things is that in the dir, where I am running that script, I have 22 of files named: bed_chr_1.bed, bed_chr_2.bed...What script suppose to do is pick just those bed files, which have this number extension _#, found from unique(x$chr) command. In this case (as seen in my problem above), I would need .bed files from bed_chr_1.bed until bed_chr_22.bed (total 15 of them), excluding ones with extension 5,8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18. And then on those selected /bed files I need to perform operations in x00, x11 and everything bellow. Can you please edit your script so that it does this. Thanks

Comment: The answer as shown performs this action:
First it will load whichever file is in the variable 'file_names' (located in initial dir) (this will be placed in the variable x)
Second from x it extracts the number the desired column (x[, file_column], replace file column by the name of the column) and converts it into file names (bed_chr_[number].bed) 
Third: it loads all of these files and performs said actions. This is performed by the lapply (which applied function over list or vector) The result is saved as a list in xx (contains x00, x11, x22 etc)) 
fifth: it combines them into one

Comment: variable, named x_final (using rbindlist, [same as rbind(x,y)]) 
Sixth: i output the combined variables writes the entire combined output into a single file (the very last line before closing "}") after renaming the column 'pvalue' as marked in your question.

Comment: I have added a few comments, and added a single 'unique' which i can see was forgotten. For the remaining questions use: 
?lapply
?fread
?paste0
etc. to get a view of how each function works, to better understand how the code functions.

Comment: I can see now that you added something in code but it seems that something has to be commented out, can you please double check.

Comment: Try to perform any changes on your own. :-) 
The code is extensive and should provide a versatile way of handling dynamic file transformations
One of the best ways to understand how the code works it to take out a single piece, and try to get it to work.

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for your patience. I did some changes, please see my EDIT above and if you can let me know what I am doing wrong there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187073/discussion-between-oliver-and-anikam).